# ¿Como comparar dos tablas de SQL y sacar los comunes?

Tags: sql-server

Ambas tienen la mismo cabecera, y me gustaría saber cuántos y que datos son comunes en dos tablas. Sus cabeceras son: Telefono, nombre, dirección

Y me gustaría saber que números son comunes en ambos ficheros

```
select * from [server].[dbo].[tabla1]
select * from [server].[dbo].[tabla2]
```

Comment: Has probado algo? Tu pregunta es de mala calidad y si no la editas añadiendo que has probado y algun tipo de fuente de datos de ejemplo probablemente termine cerrada

Comment: Hola Pablo podrias decirnos si las respuestas dadas te resultaron utiles y marcar como aceptada la que mas te haya ayudado y si lo deseas puedes emitir tu voto tambien, gracias

Comment: no sabía eso de cerrarlas, perdona

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hay muchas formas de hacerlo, puede ser un `JOIN`:

```
SELECT *
FROM server.dbo.tabla1 t1
JOIN server.dbo.tabla2 t2
   ON t1.Telefono = t2.Telefono
   AND t1.nombre = t2.nombre
   AND t1.direccion = t2.direccion
;
```

O quizás puedes usar `INTERSECT`:

```
SELECT *
FROM server.dbo.tabla1 t1

INTERSECT

SELECT *
FROM server.dbo.tabla2 t2
;
```

Y varias más....

Comment: muchas gracias, me funciono perfectamente

Answer (score 2):

Puedes usar también subconsultas:

```
select * 
from [server].[dbo].[tabla1]
where telefono in (
                   select telefono 
                   from [server].[dbo].[tabla2]
                  )
```

De esta forma utilizamos el **operador in** para ver que teléfonos hay en común entre la **tabla1** y la **tabla2**. La subconsulta interna seleccionará todos los teléfonos de **tabla2** y usando el **operador in** determinaremos los teléfonos en común entre ambas tablas.